# How to project data points onto a manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Given a real manifold M with a parametrization P, how do you project a set of data points D onto the manifold? A method not using the inverse of the diffeomorphism taking open sets to R^n is not what I'm looking for as a side note.

Comment: If your manifold $M$ is compact, it has an $\epsilon$-neighborhood $U$ in $\Bbb R^n$ with the property that every point in $U$ has a unique closest point in $M$. If all your data points lie within $U$, then you're in good shape. Otherwise, you won't have a unique closest point. For example, if $M$ is the unit sphere centered at $0$ and $0\in D$, you have no unique choice of projection of $0$ onto $M$.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.